# Point CNAME record to API Gateway Endpoint host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, serverless

I have a deployed API Gateway Regional Enpoint in the form of:

```
https://some-id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/my-path/
```

I know that in order to have a custom domain like `www.my-domain.com` resolve to `https://some-id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/my-path/` I must setup an api gateway custom domain and cloudfront distribution.

However, I'm only interested in having `www.my-domain.com` resolve to `some-id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` (without the path). This is so I don't need to update my clients if the deployment id changes.

I tried setting up a Route53 CNAME record with the value of `some-id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` for `api.my-domain.com` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please be more specific than *"it doesn't work."*  What does it do?  Did you also actually configure a your domain name as a custom domain?  Just the CNAME isn't enough, but you don't need a CloudFront distribution.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the process of adding a custom domain to API Gateway, however I'm waiting for this [issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=271806&tstart=0) to be resolved, since I want to do it through cloud formation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to leave your custom domain without a base mapping. From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html):

> If you do not set any base mapping under a custom domain name, the resulting API's base URL is the same as the custom domain (e.g., https://api.example.com.) In this case, the custom domain name cannot support more than one API.